# ORACLE - Use Trigger to Update Data in another DB

Tags: oracle

I am new to creating triggers in ORACLE. My scenario is as follows:

I have two Databases on the same server - A & B

When the value of Column X is updated in Table AA of Database A, I need to update the same value(s) of Column Y in Table BB of Database B.

These tables are linked into an Access front-end and set up as one-to-many (one Column X to many Column Y's), but I cannot set up cascading updates in Access when the tables are linked in. In ORACLE, these 2 tables come from 2 separate databases.

How can I create this trigger so that when Column X of Table AA in Database A is updated, the trigger goes to Column Y in Table BB of Database B, checks for the OLD value of Column X and updates found instances with the NEW value of Column X?

Any help provided would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify some question

Is update table is bi-directional or uni-directional to your environment?

Trigger will be heavy once the number or transaction and amount of data increase, so what is your exact purpose to replicate the data to target system?